# Excel 2016 XML data import from webservice needs dual update to execute update

Tags: excel, web-services, data-import

I'm experiencing a weird problem when trying to import XML data to Excel 2016.

I have a Webservice created in C# which conforms to XML standards.

In Excel 2016 I use the "Data"->"From internet"->"Pasted URL to the Webservice".
When I finish the Excel import dialog I get a nice table representation of my data from the Webservice.

But when the output changes in the Webservice and I hit the "Update" option when right-clicking the datatable - the data doesn't update in the datatable!

If I repeat and click update again (exactly the same operation as before) - the data updates in the datatable...

Anyone knows how to overcome this strange behavior?

For reference I also tried hitting the update and update all in the ribbon under data and tried any possible combinations under the connection properties - to no avail.

And I also tried to reload the XML in the browser - here the data is updated instantly - so It doesn't seem to be related to caching. I can see Excel writes connecting shortly on the first run - but no update occurs.

Comment: I removed [C#] and [xml] tags those are not related directly ;).